# I am trying to make Simple Linear Regression Model with the salary data csv file , and there are 35 data points . how do i split it in 80-20?

Tags: python

```
# split train test data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

# import required modules and train the ML algorithm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

i am getting the error-
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [28, 7]

Comment: The order `train_test_split` gives is `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` as stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Answer (score 0):

By salary csv data, i will take this one as example
https://www.kaggle.com/karthickveerakumar/salary-data-simple-linear-regression

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 

#Import the dataset
salary_data=pd.read_csv("/mnt/c/Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/Salary_Data.csv")

# Here you can split your dataset between train and test using 80% for train
X_train,  X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(salary_data["YearsExperience"], salary_data["Salary"], test_size=0.2, random_state=1)


#Then you can fit your linear model on train dataset 
#Here the goal is to modelize salary considering years of XP
regressor = LinearRegression() 
model = regressor.fit(X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1),y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1))

#Let's plot our model prediction on whole data and compare to real data
plt.title("Salary/Years of XP")
plt.ylabel("Salary $")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.plot(salary_data["YearsExperience"],salary_data["Salary"],color="blue",label="real data")
plt.plot(salary_data["YearsExperience"],model.predict(salary_data["YearsExperience"].values.reshape(-1,1)),color="red",label="linear model")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you can see that the relation between years of xp and salary is well fitted by a simple linear regression model